# OS OpenSpace map in a .NET (Windows Forms) WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a WinForms application written in C# (currently targeting .NET Framework 4). I also have an ASP.NET MVC4 web application which is supposed to present a real-time map of vehicle positions using GPS (at the moment it just has some static flag markers). The map is created using the Ordnance Survey OpenSpace API, and seems to work fine when viewed in Firefox and IE.

The problem is when I try and view the map in the WebBrowser control I have on one of the forms on the desktop application. It looks fine to begin with, but after looking arround the map and zooming in and out I few times the map rips itself to peices. The wrong part of the country appears behind the static flag markers and the map is broken into several segments, which do not align correctly. I tried to post an image, but was not allowed.

Has anyone got any ideas what could be going wrong?